# How to redirect output of an entire ZSH shell script from within script itself?

Tags: shell, zsh

So I want to log the output (stdout & stderr) of my non-interactive zsh shell scripts to both stdout and a log file, and to configure that capability from within the script itself.

With bash scripts, I've used the following and it works perfectly:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
exec &> >(tee -a /path/to/logfile)
```

Everything that follows prints both to stdout and to a log file.

But when I change the script to run with `#!/bin/zsh`, the script will hang when it gets to the `exec` line.

For example, if the script were this:

```sh
#!/bin/zsh
echo 'test'
exec &> >(tee -a /path/to/logfile)
```

Then when running it, *stdout* will hang showing this:

```
+test_script.sh:2> echo test
```

Annoyingly, in the hanged state, *Ctrl-C* won't kill the process. Only way I know to get control of my terminal back is to background the process with *Ctrl-Z* and then kill the pid. (Took me a while to figure that out.)

Anyway, I'd like to know how I can achieve the same result in zsh. Ideally I'd also really like to understand why zsh is behaving differently from bash.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you read the zsh manual about exec?

Comment: Yeah. I know I must be missing something, but I can't understand the difference between the bash and zsh execs.

zsh exec: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html
bash exec: https://ss64.com/bash/exec.html

Comment: is `&>` a valid zsh redirection, or is it a bashism? (I'm not a zsh user so I really don't know)

Comment: @glennjackman, `&>` was initially a bashism (zsh had `>&` for that instead like in csh), but zsh did add support for that for bash compatibility in 1996.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I (finally) discovered a way to do this in a way compatible with both bash and zsh:

```
#!/bin/bash or #!/bin/zsh

exec > >(tee -a path/to/logfile) 2>&1
```

As a bonus, I also discovered how to change redirection of logging to different files within the same script.

```
#!/bin/bash or #!/bin/zsh

exec 3>&1
exec > >(tee -a path/to/logfile-1) 2>&1

echo "Copies stdout and stderr to first logfile"

exec >&3
exec > >(tee -a path/to/logfile-2) 2>&1

echo "Copies stdout and stderr to second logfile (and not the first)"
```

I admit I don't fully understand why this works, and why exec behaves differently with what I tried before, but I'm using this method now with no issues.

Thank you to all who've responded!